# Disable Chrome iframe security for just one website

Tags: web, iframe

I need to disable Chrome's iframe security for just *one* page so that I can access the contents of cross-domain websites.

I have complete control over this browser, this can use extensions.

I have been looking for a way to do this for the past hour or so. No luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out this extension to bypass when development, this will allow you to resolve the issue with cross-domain issue:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cross-domain-cors/mjhpgnbimicffchbodmgfnemoghjakai

Disclaim: I am the owner of this extension.